# Firebase cocoapod problem "One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I've got a problem when I install pods:
'Firebase/Analytics'
'Firebase/Auth'
'Firebase/Core'
'Firebase/Firestore'

When I launch the app I get a lot of classes with their localizations and sentences  "Class is implemented in both. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined"

I can't get solutions for days.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Documentation [Add Firebase to an app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods) is a great place to start!

You'll find info about setting up your podfile and to answer your question, this is mentioned

> The Firebase iOS library Firebase/Core is no longer needed. This SDK
> included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics

So your podfile would look like this

```
platform :ios, ‘12.0’

# Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

# Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
# For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```

to start creating your podfile, in the console, navigate to your project directory and do this

```
pod init
```

which will create a default podfile which you can add the Firebase pods to.

If you're having other pod issues, you may want to remove your current pods and re-do it. Start with

```
pod deintegrate
```

to remove any existing pods

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseAnalytics` is a static library and cannot be linked to multiple dynamic frameworks and the main app.

More details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/firebase_in_libraries.md.

Comment: Ok, so I've deleted FirebaseAnalytics but I still get this message. When I use physical device or iOS 13.0 on simulator  it works (with iOS 14 it doesn't).

Comment: `Firebase/Core` is a synonym for `Firebase/Analytics`